# A query to get data of sheet in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I add a small table

[image]

To call the information on this sheet, I am doing it this way:

```
var hojaCalculo = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1d3UuYJyHhsgfsdgshfghumtP4BX5bee2M");
var hojaDatos = hojaCalculo.getSheetByName("lista_sites");
var numColumns = hojaDatos.getLastColumn();
var ultimaFila = hojaDatos.getLastRow();   
var row = hojaDatos.getRange(1, 1, ultimaFila, numColumns).getValues();

for (var i = 1; i < row.length; i++) {  
 //the content and conditionals
 var id_site =row[i][0].toString();
}
```

As I have few records, the search for what I need will be quick, according to the conditions I set. but in truth my list has more than 3000 records, and then the search is slow, since it goes through each record.

You can make a query as if when doing a table in a database, like this:

```
 select * from table where nro_incidencias>18
```

This would be so as not to go through all the records

I found this code:

```
var spreadsheetId = '1d3UuYJyHhsgfsdgshfghumtP4BX5bee2M';
var targetRange = 'lista_sites!A:C';
var SQL = 'select A, C where B >= 18'
var Query = '=QUERY('+targetRange+',\"'+SQL+'\")'

var currentDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId)
var tempSheet = currentDoc.insertSheet();  
var pushQuery = tempSheet.getRange(1, 1).setFormula(Query);
var pullResult = tempSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

for (var i = 1; i < pullResult .length; i++) {  
 //the content and conditionals
 var id_site =pullResult[i][0].toString();
}
```

As you can see, it makes a query to the content of list_sites, but what it does is create it in a new sheet, and just there to be able to work with a new content. creating a new sheet also causes a delay, in addition the query is shown with a setformula. Will there be any way to combine it to be with a data collection, without the need to create another sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values with `=QUERY(lista_sites!A:C,"select A, C where B >= 18")`.
- In this case, you want to retrieve the values without inserting new sheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In this answer, the values are directly retrieved with the Query Language.

#### Sample script:

```
var spreadsheetId = '###';  // Please set the spreadsheet ID.
var targetSheet = 'lista_sites';  // Please set the sheet name.
var query = 'select A, C where B >= 18';  // Please set the query for retrieving the values.

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
var sheetId = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getSheetId();
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/gviz/tq?gid=" + sheetId + "&tqx=out:csv&tq=" + encodeURIComponent(query);
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
var values = Utilities.parseCsv(res.getContentText());
Logger.log(values)
```

- In this case, the values are returned as CSV format. So the CSV data is parsed. By this, `values` is 2 dimensional array.

#### References:

- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)
- [parseCsv(csv)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: This solution was the best they could give me. but now I have a problem, the csv no longer returns me. what should it be since the code did not modify it a long time ago

Comment: @Kevincs7 Thank you for replying. When I tested this script just now, I could confirm that the script worked. I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation. So in order to correctly understand about it, can you post it including the detail information as new question? By this, I would like to confirm your situation and the issue. Also it will help users think of the issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Sorry, it was fixed, but it took a while to load. a query, I make this query several times, I mean several times I call a different csv, are these csv stored somewhere or only used at the moment?

Comment: @Kevincs7 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal (what you want to do). So in order to correctly understand about it, can you post it including the detail information as new question? By this, I would like to confirm your situation and the issue. Also it will help users think of the issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I created the following question, I hope you understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59939134/are-the-csv-files-generated-with-parsecsv-stored-somewhere

Comment: @Kevincs7 Thank you for your response. I would like to check it.

Comment: what language do you speak?

Comment: @Kevincs7 Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, although I cannot understand about your replying, I'm Japanese. So my mother language is Japanese.

Comment: 私のクエリは次のとおりでした... parseCSV関数を使用するたびに、クラウドでCSVファイルが作成されますか？
  クラウドに最大のストレージ容量はありますか？
このCSVファイルはどこに保存されますか？

Comment: @Kevincs7 Thank you for replying. I could understand about your replying in Japanese language. But from your replying and new question you posted, unfortunately, I cannot see the vision of the issue and your goal. By this, I cannot still think of it. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. When I could correctly understand about your issue, I would like to think of it.