# Are the csv files generated with parseCsv stored somewhere?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm doing a web in google script.
I have done the following search method:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzxWqtu9bIhTXb2zP9fsOoFFqe3St1T1C91ZDVu747GCWxrR1c/exec

my code Codigo.gs is:

```
  function doGet(e) {

  Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
  if(!e.parameter.page){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate();
}

var template=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter.page)
template.action=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
return template.evaluate();

  return HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

}

/*****************************  buscar asignado de trabajo  ********************************************/
function get_AsignadoSS(k){
 var sPers_asignado=k.pers_asignado;
 var sReg_Asig="LIMA";
 var contenido_ul="";

  var spreadsheetId_r = '1ykYOd5PWP5aZEREnRIqkPMLT1pSYrcRA6mfQHl7bL4I';  // Please set the spreadsheet ID.
  var targetSheet_r = 'Personal';  // Please set the sheet name.


 if(sPers_asignado!="") {

   var query_r = 'select A, B where ( B contains "'+sPers_asignado.toUpperCase()+'" or A contains "'+sPers_asignado.toUpperCase()+'" ) AND E = "'+sReg_Asig+'"';  // Please set the query for retrieving the values.

   var ss_r = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId_r);
   var sheetId_r = ss_r.getSheetByName(targetSheet_r).getSheetId();
   var url_r = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId_r + "/gviz/tq?gid=" + sheetId_r + "&tqx=out:csv&tq=" + encodeURIComponent(query_r);
   var res_r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_r, {headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
   var row = Utilities.parseCsv(res_r.getContentText());
   //https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z4izqpus1yE6rZiqY1ttCEYA3NO3d7J3bZ4oFgQW330/gviz/tq?gid=Usuarios&tqx=out:csv&tq=encodeURIComponent('select A, B where ( B contains "li" )')    
   if(row.length>6){
      var maximo=7;
   }else{
      var maximo=row.length;
   }
   //var contenido_ul=sCodigo_site;
   var contenido_ul=contenido_ul+"<ul id='country-list' class='list-group'>";
   for (var i = 1; i < maximo; i++) {
     var nombre_site = row[i][1].toString();
     var pasar_nom_site='"'+row[i][1].toString()+'"';
     var contenido_ul=contenido_ul+"<li class='list-group-item' style='text-align: left' onClick='selectCountry("+pasar_nom_site+");'>"+nombre_site+"</li>";
   }
      var contenido_ul=contenido_ul+"</ul>";
   }

  if(sPers_asignado=="") {
     var contenido_ul="";
   }
     return contenido_ul;
   }
```

and my code Index.html is

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>
  function buscar_asignado(){
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(get_Asignado).get_AsignadoSS(document.forms[0]);
   }
function get_Asignado(data){
    //alert("tt");
    $("#suggesstion-box-asignado").show();
    $("#suggesstion-box-asignado").html(data);
    }

function selectCountry(codigo) {
    $("#pers_asignado").val(codigo);
    $("#suggesstion-box-asignado").hide();    
}

/*----------------codigo esencial para conectar con codigo.GS----------------------*/
function preventFormSubmit() {
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
  for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();    
    });
  }   
}
window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);


</script>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
     <base target="_top">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.6/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css"> 
     </head>
    <body>
   <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: red;color: white;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px">
     <CENTER><label style="font-size: 30px;font-family: monospace;font-weight: normal;color:white">ACTIVIDADES</label></CENTER>
    </div>

   <div id="todo_contenido"style="display:block">
      <center><br><br>
       <div class="modal-content" style="width:95%">
       <div class="modal-body"> 
       <form id="datosTrabajo" name="datosTrabajo">

          <div class="form-group row">
             <label for="pers_asignado" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Asignado:</label>
             <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pers_asignado" name="pers_asignado" onkeyup="buscar_asignado();" placeholder="Nombre Asignado..." style="background-color: white">
              <div id="suggesstion-box-asignado" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1"></div>
             </div>
             <label for="tipo_trabajo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Tipo Trabajo:</label>
             <div class="col-sm-4">
                   <select class="form-control" id="tipo_trabajo" name="tipo_trabajo" >
                        <option value="">Select Tipo Equipo:</option>
                        <option value="ATPs">ATPs</option>
                        <option value="Caceria Interferencia">Caceria Interferencia</option>
                        <option value="Desbalance RTWP">Desbalance RTWP</option>
                        <option value="Respaldo Baterias">Respaldo Baterias</option>
                        <option value="Site Audit">Site Audit</option>
                        <option value="Trabajos TX">Trabajos TX</option>
                        <option value="Prueba de Llamadas">Prueba de Llamadas</option>
                        <option value="PIM Logico">PIM Logico</option>
                        <option value="Administrativo">Administrativo</option>
                        <option value="OTROS">OTROS</option>
                      </select>
              </div>
           </div>
          </form>
         </div>
      </div>
     <br>
     </center>
     </div>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.6/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Then each time a letter is entered, a new search is made. In this case the search becomes normal, since it only occurs in 100 records. But my question is whether it is every time a new query is made (every time a digit is entered). These csv files are stored somewhere. The problem I have is that I have a more extensive code, which searches 6000 records; but you are not doing the search, and there are personnel who connect to this website to enter information and are having problems.

Or will there be some other way to do this type of search in Google Script?

Answer (score 0):

`parseCsv()` - Returns a tabular 2D array representation of a CSV string.  So

```
var A=Utilities.parseCsv(csvdata);
sheet.getRange(1,1,A.length,A[0].length).setValues(A);
```

will put the data into sheet.

The csv and the 2d array's are not stored anywhere unless you stored somewhere.

Comment: with the query that I pass the data from code.gs to index.html, but I don't know how I would do it with your code that you have added

Comment: Your var row is a 2d Array, even if it's only 1 row.  If it's only 1 row then row.length will be one.

Comment: You might find it valuable to look at your code in the debugger so you can see what your actually getting.  I find it difficult to read your code since I can't get many context clues since I don't speak or write any other language.

Comment: I think you are putting the second element of every row in `var row` into an unordered list in your html.