# data query problem with google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

Since yesterday I get the problem when I make a query to a sheet to bring information. The code to bring information is the following:

```
var s_usuario="c123";
var spreadsheetId = 'myid';  // Please set the spreadsheet ID.
var targetSheet = "Usuarios";  // Please set the sheet name.
var usuario =s_usuario.toUpperCase();

var query = 'select B where A = "'+usuario+'"';  // Please set the query for retrieving the values.

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
var sheetId = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getSheetId();
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/gviz/tq?gid=" + sheetId + "&tqx=out:csv&tq=" + encodeURIComponent(query);
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
var row = Utilities.parseCsv(res.getContentText());
var maximo=row.length;

  
for (var i = 0; i < maximo; i++) {
  var mostrar =row[i][0].toString();
}

return mostrar
```

What should I modify so that the query can be given? I think there was an update in the language

[image]

Comment: What's the complete error?

Comment: nothing returns

Comment: I hope you realize that you are only returning the last entry in `row` with this code:`for (var i = 0; i < maximo; i++) {
  var mostrar =row[i][0].toString();
}

return mostrar`

Comment: I have added a photo of the error that I get

Comment: I think it's may be the last little loop in your question take a look at my answer.

Comment: You might wish to run you error message through a translator if you want it to be useful to most of the volunteers here on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want:

```
var mostrar='';
for (var i=0;i<maximo; i++) {
  mostrar +=row[i][0].toString();
}
return mostrar;
```

or even:

```
var mostrar=row.map(r=>{return r[0];});
return mostrar.join(',');
```

Probably everything else is okay since you copied it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59262678/7215091)

Comment: Will there be another way to do the query? is that it is not returning any value, and I see that the code is fine

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you saying that the query is `res.getContentText()` is empty because that's not what I'm suggesting.  But of course I don't really know because I'm not going to run it. I'm just saying that I think it's your it's your ouput  routine that appears to be the problem.

Comment: How do you suggest that I can make the query

Comment: I don't suggest anything.  I'm simply saying that the problem is probably in here `for (var i = 0; i < maximo; i++) {
  var mostrar =row[i][0].toString();
}

return mostrar` and I would suggest replacing it with my answers or making a new version yourslelf.

Answer (score 0):

### This is a new [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/175141974) related to the `UrlFetchApp`

It seems to already worked on, so hopefully the issue is of temporarily nature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution, but I can also say that in the past 2-3 days my scripts also all started failing that use `var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);`  My scripts are on a schedule and all of them fail at any line that uses this.  I see that you are using UrlFetchApp as well.  My first failure happened at Dec 8, 2020, 3:53:50 AM

Hopefully this can help figure out what is going on.  Here is the specific error I get on mine:

```
Exception: Unexpected error: https://...org/..xxxx/..xxx.csv (line 242, file "Code")
```

I am very interested in the solution that works for you, perhaps it can help me as well.